# AWS Load Balancer routing for different subdomains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I'm trying to setup my website (on AWS). I have a t2.micro instance running on the us-east-1 region, and a Load Balancer (availability zones are us-east-1d and us-east-1c). I bought my domain using route 53, and also used the certificate manager to generate my SSL certificate (which I have attached to the load balancer). 
My problem is that the load balancer seems to always send me to the root domain and it completely ignores the 2 subdomains I have setup on the EC2 instance. They were working perfectly until I created the ELB. So how can I get the subdomains working with the ELB? Or is this not the proper way of doing it? Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

You need to look at the [application load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html)'s [rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-rules). You can direct traffic based on the requested host name, or path. For example you can send `app.example.com` to one [target group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html) or `blog.example.com` to another group. Or you can route paths to individual target groups; for example `example.com` goes to your site, but `example.com/cart` goes to a microservice running your shopping cart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did, but the way I set it up was my main application example.com runs on the folder: /var/www/html. And each subdomain runs on its own folder inside www: /var/www/sub.example.com/public_html (I plan on later moving the main app to /var/www/example.com/public_html). I checked the documentation, and can't find a way to route the subdomains to each folder above the /var/www/html

Comment: @BrunoPereira the balancer does not know where the directories are, on your instance.  It does not send traffic "to" a subdomain, but to the target web server process. The web server running on the instance is solely responsible for serving the correct content based on the site being requested.  The issue (and the solution) is in your web server configuration.

Comment: You said they were working perfectly before the ELB, did you have virtual hosts configured? How were you reaching these subfolders using your subdomain before?